# How can I express the following integral as special function?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics

How can I express the following integral as special function? where the integral is from 0 to infinity

$ f_{int}(x)=\int^{\infty}_{0}dy\frac{e^{(-x+y)}}{(1+e^{(-x+y)^{2}})\sqrt{y}} $

Comment: Why do you believe that such an expression is possible? It is not too hard to get an infinite sum of Bessel functions...

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a closed form expression even for $x=0$.